# Can you find integral of this function.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Question:

Consider

> $$F(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x-a) \ \sin(x-b)  \ \sin(x-c)}$$

Then, how to compute $\int F(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$?

**Edit**:

I have tried what I know about integral solving methods. I have tried doing it by parts taking second function as 1 it turned out to be a mess. I tried multiplying and dividing by constants having sin function in tricky ways but still a mess.

Comment: @Dmoreno i have tried what i know about integral solving methods. I have tried doing it by parts taking second function as 1 it turned out to be a mess. I tried multiplying and dividing by constants having sin function in tricky ways but still a mess

Comment: Hint: Using $\sin(x-a) := \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i(x-a)} - e^{-i(x-a)}\right)$, change variable to $z = e^{ix}$ and then partial fraction decomposition. If you don't like to deal with complex number, change variable to $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$ which will turn the integrand to a rational function of $t$.

Comment: Distant cousin : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778479/int-frac1-sinx-a-sinx-b-dx

Comment: @labbhattacharjee interesting. I didn't remember I have actually answered this distant cousin before :-p

Answer (score 3):

Following @acchilehui's suggestion, take advantage of the fact:

$$\sin{(x-\theta)} = \sin{x}\cos{\theta} - \cos{x} \sin{\theta},$$

and make use of the [**Weierstrass substitution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to write your integral as follows:

> $$ I = \int \frac{2 \, \mathrm{d} t}{(2 t  \, \cos{a} - (1-t^2) \,  \sin{a})(2 t  \, \cos{b} - (1-t^2) \,  \sin{a})(2 t  \, \cos{c} - (1-t^2) \,  \sin{c})}. $$

It seems that the denominator can be nicely factorized up as follows (perhabps this is the tricky part):

$$\text{Den} = (t+\cot{a/2})(t+\cot{b/2})(t+\cot{c/2})(t-\tan{a/2})(t-\tan{b/2})(t-\tan{c/2})$$

so you can perform a partial fraction decomposition as follows:

$$ I = \int Q(t) \, \mathrm{d}t  = \int \sum_i \frac{A_i}{t-t_i} \, \mathrm{d}t,$$

where $t_i$ are the roots of $\text{Den}$ and $A_i$ are given by (see [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895290/solve-ode-1x3y-x/895358#895358) to see how it works):

$$A_i = \lim_{t\to t_i} Q(t)(t-t_i), $$

which leads to the solution

> $$\color{blue}{I = \sum_i A_i \log{|t-t_i|}}$$

Substituting back $t = \tan{x/2}$ gives you the result in terms of $x$. Hope this helps!

Cheers.

Comment: You forget the factors $A_i$ in your last expression. I have not computed what they are
but I don't think they are all $1$. In any event, if I do the substitution $z = e^{ix}$, 
the integral has the form
$$
  \frac{\log\tan\left(\displaystyle\frac{x-a}{2}\right)}{\sin(a-b)\sin(a-c)}
+ \frac{\log\tan\left(\displaystyle\frac{x-b}{2}\right)}{\sin(b-c)\sin(b-a)}
+ \frac{\log\tan\left(\displaystyle\frac{x-c}{2}\right)}{\sin(c-a)\sin(c-b)}
+ \text{const.}
$$

Comment: Of course! Thanks @achillehui. I guess the terms of the sum can be re-arranged pairwise so my solution and yours will match (I hope that).

Comment: It should match. I'll leave my previous comment around for a while and hopefully the OP can work out the $A_i$. In any event, +1 for this.